# Give a hint about local MTA for web development

Tags: php, email, mta

I'll try to explain what I want.

I have a PHP script that send emails to different REAL addresses. I don't like these emails goes to Internet, just redirect all of them to my local mail (user@localhost) or simple write emails to local file (with headers for sure).

I'm using Linux on my desktop.

Comment: Is this for testing purposes?  Why not send the messages to the local accounts?

Comment: Why don't you simply set some flag somewhere i.e. `$debugmode = true` and if debugmode is true send all mails to a predefined debugemailaddress?

Comment: I would like use this for debugging on several projects and could not change the code. For example, I'm working with Wordpress now, not my own script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Setup Postfix/Courier/Nullmailer/Sendmail/whatever SMTP server you are using to deliver all mail locally. (Hint: https://serverfault.com/questions/144325/how-to-redirect-all-postfix-emails-to-one-external-email-address)
2. If you want a solution only for PHP, then it would probably be best to create a class or special function in PHP that checks for some constant or variable (eg, 'DEV', or '$debug'), and when that variable is set to true, you send only to the local email address.

(1) May be a good option if you are always and only using this computer for testing purposes, and don't have to worry about accidentally sending out an email to a real person, and (2) is better if you have a specific project you are debugging temporarily.

Comment: Unfortunately #2 is not for me, I would like use this for debugging on several projects and could not change the code.
I've searched in google for something like #1 for half of the day and cannot find the solution yet (

Comment: Updated my answer with a link